# Show UISearchBar in UINavigationBar animated iOS >= 7.0

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have my FeedViewController contained in UINavigationController. So the navBar looks like this:
[image: navbar original]

Then I expect that user will tap on scopeButton at the right and will see the UISearchBar with scopeBar in UINavigationBar animated. I have created a SearchViewController with UISearchDisplayController and put UISearchBar at the top of the SearchController.view and I added this controller as ChildViewController to the FeedViewController. When user taps the scope button I hide the navigationBar with NO animation and shows my SearchViewController.view. But this looks like this:
[image: searchBar mess up]

I have tried to set background of my UISearchBar with many variants:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[GeneralHelper imageFromColor:[GeneralHelper orangeColor] forSize:CGSizeMake(1.f, 1.f)]
                                        forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny
                                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[GeneralHelper imageFromColor:[GeneralHelper orangeColor] forSize:CGSizeMake(1.f, 1.f)]];
```

And some others. But I still have no luck :( Please help me to understand what am I doing wrong! Thanks!

Maybe my concept of building view with UISearchBar is wrong or something else. I really don't know.

Comment: Why as a child, why not push the search viewcontroller?

Comment: Because I want nice animation :) I will push it if I find no answer.